# Understanding `traceback.format_exception_only()`

Tags: python, exception

I wanted to just print exception type and message.

I initially tried:

```
try:
    raise Exception("duh!!!")
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

But this only printed exception message.

```
 duh!!!
```

Then I went through the whole [`traceback` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#) and I felt [`traceback.format_exception_only()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception_only) is the one I am looking for.

So i tried it as follows:

```
try:
    raise Exception("duh!!!")
except:
    etype, evalue, tb = sys.exc_info()
    print(traceback.format_exception_only(etype, evalue)))
```

and it printed following:

```
['Exception: duh!!!\n']
```

which looked a bit unexpected to me. So I re-read the doc for this method. It says following:

> Format the exception part of a traceback. The arguments are the exception type and value such as given by `sys.last_type` and `sys.last_value`. The return value is a list of strings, each ending in a newline. Normally, the list contains a single string; however, for `SyntaxError` exceptions, it contains several lines that (when printed) display detailed information about where the syntax error occurred. The message indicating which exception occurred is the always last string in the list.

So I understood that the doc says its a list, which is why there is a list in the output `[...]`. Also the doc says each line ends in newline, thats why there  is `\n` in the output. But I dont get when there will be multiple lines in case of `SyntaxError`? I am not able to produce `SyntaxError` which will result in multiple lines in the return value of `format_exception_only()`.

Also it suddenly clicked to me that I can simply do

```
try:
    raise Exception("duh!!!")
except:
    etype, evalue, tb = sys.exc_info()
    print('{}: {}'.format(etype.__name__, evalue))
```

to get

```
Exception: duh!!!
```

But then how `format_exception_only()` adds more value to this?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is, you can add a simple syntax error using say `exec('1 a = b')`: https://ideone.com/PFgwH4 or import a module that has syntax error. How it adds multiple lines? Well, there's a specific check for it https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/traceback.py#L565.

Answer (score -1):

Python is open source so you can view the implementation and decide what the extra value is for yourself:

```
    if self.exc_type is None:
        yield _format_final_exc_line(None, self._str)
        return

    stype = self.exc_type.__qualname__
    smod = self.exc_type.__module__
    if smod not in ("__main__", "builtins"):
        stype = smod + '.' + stype

    if not issubclass(self.exc_type, SyntaxError):
        yield _format_final_exc_line(stype, self._str)
    else:
        yield from self._format_syntax_error(stype)
```

It's a fairly simple function so yes, per your question if you ignore the parts of the functionality you don't use it doesn't add much value to you.

Of course, you're now on the hook for maintaining your code if there's any Exception changes in the future, or if turns out the Exception raiser starts returning SyntaxErrors, or any other edge cases that come in the future.

Reduced maintenance and increased readability (because everyone knows what the library code does) are the two relatively universal advantages of using standard library code.

Comment: "Python is open source so you can view the implementation and decide what the extra value is for yourself" risks being interpreted as snark.